# Reciprocal Squareroot Birkhoff Integrable?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Is the reciprocal of the squareroot Birkhoff integrable over the unit interval:
$$\int_{(0,1]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}<\infty?$$
Then that would be an example of a function not Riemann but Birkhoff integrable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Lebesgue integrable thus Birkhoff integrable.